# How to disable creating html example folder in Apache

Tags: apache, laravel, vagrant

I am creating a provision shell script file and in Laravel I have a public folder and not html like in a default Apache install.

So, I end up deleting html and index.php example file all the time.

Is there any option while installing apache2 on my system to not create html folder and the example file?

Comment: show us your VagrantFile . You should use something like this: `config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", :owner=> 'vagrant', :mount_options => ['dmode=777', 'fmode=777']`

Comment: I don't think this is Vagrant related. The apache installation creates this folder and file and not Vagrant. Anyway, this is what I have in my provision file `apt-get -y install php5 apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php-apc > /dev/null 2>&1
`

Comment: I see, but why not delete after installation? See example: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/provisioning.html

Comment: yeah, that's one possibility too.